# How to annotate PS or PDF from (Linux) command line without losing quality?

Tags: pdf, command-line, postscript, adobe-illustrator

Is there any command line tool for Linux that will allow me to annotate a PS or PDF file with text or a particular font, color, and size with no loss of quality?  I have tried ImageMagick's convert, and the resulting PDF is of pretty poor quality.

I have a template originally authored in Adobe Illustrator, and I would like to generate PDFs from it with names in certain places.  I have a huge list of names, so I would like to do this in a batch (not interactively).

If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate hearing them.
Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to create PDF form and fill it with [pdftk fill_form](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-fill-form) in batch:

```
$ pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output out.pdf flatten
```

Form data should be in [Forms Data Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forms_Data_Format#Forms_Data_Format_.28FDF.29) (it's just XML file with field names and values specified).
Note the `flatten` command. It is required to convert filled form to plain document.

Another way is to create set of PDF documents "with names in certain places" and transparent background, and [pdftk stamp](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-stamp) each of them over the template:

```
$ pdftk template.pdf stamp words.pdf output out.pdf
```

Comment: This sounds interesting-- I will attempt to see if I can get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish this would be to hack the postscript file itself. It used to be that AI files *were* postscript files, and you could modify them directly; I don't know if that's true anymore. So you may have to export it.

For simplicity, I assume there's a single page. Therefore, at the very end there will be a single call to `showpage` (perhaps through another name). Any drawing commands performed before showpage will show up on the page.

You may need to reinitialize the graphics state (`initgraphics`), as the rest of the document may have left it all funny, expecting showpage to clean up before anyone notices.

To place text, you'll need to set a new font (the old one was invalidated by initgraphics) measure the location in points (72 points/inch, 28.3465 points/cm).

```
/Palatino-Roman 17 selectfont %so much prettier than Times
x y moveto
(new text) show
```

To do the merging, you can use perl: emit the beginning of the document as a HERE-document, construct some text-writing lines by program, emit the tail of the document. Here's an example of [generating postscript with PERL](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.misc/browse_thread/thread/9fbed61f16c42e43/)

Or you can take data from the command-line (with ghostscript) by using the `--` option (`$gs -q -- program.ps arg1 arg2 ... argn`). These arguments are accessible to the program through an array named /ARGUMENTS.

So, say you have a nice graphic of a scary clown holding a blank sign about 1 inch wide, 3 inches tall, top left corner at 4 inches from the left, 4 inches from the bottom. You can insert this code into the ps program, just before `showpage`.

```
initgraphics
/Palatino-Roman 12 selectfont
4 72 mul 4 72 mul moveto
ARGUMENTS {
    gsave show grestore 0 -14 rmoveto
} forall
```

Now you can make him say funny things (`$gs -- clown.ps "On a dark," "and stormy night..."`).